# replacing subfloor

Tags: floor, subfloor

How does one replace the sub floor?  I will redo the bathroom and need to get to the pipes under the sub floor.  This is the first layer of flooring... so it is installed before the walls went up. Half the walls are over joists the the side walls are not.  I am moving all the fixtures so I figured it would be easier to remove the subfloor, than cut a bunch of holes in the floor. I can get the old floor out. Pry in the middle and cut along the edges where the walls are.  My real question is:
DO I need to re-enforce the edges with 2 by's when I replace the subfloor?  I really do not want the flooring to move or sag at the walls when I done.  Is there another way?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to replace the whole subfloor? Can you just make holes for your pipes and patch?

Comment: Oops, replaced my earlier comment. I typed "perpendicular" where I meant to type "parallel"...  Which direction are your joists running? If they're perpendicular to the wall, I wouldn't worry about it. Presuming your subfloor is 3/4 particle board or oxboard, it's not going to sag between the joists. But if the joists are parallel to the wall you have a different problem.